Why is $*F^{\mu \nu} *F_{\mu \nu}$ not considered in Lagrangian of EM?
In Lagrangian of electromagnetism $F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$ and $*F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$ are used, where the $*$ denotes Hodge dual. But $*F^{\mu \nu} *F_{\mu \nu}$ is not used, why?
I know an indirect proof that the two used are the only possible scalars which can be used, but I don't see why the contraction of two Hodge duals cannot be used.

As knzhou pointed out in their comment, the contraction of the Hodge dual $(^\star F_{\mu\nu}) (^\star F^{\mu\nu})$ is essentially the same as $F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$ (in the sense that it is algebraically equivalent). If the metric tensor used to raise and lower indices is symmetric, then the only two independent algebraic invariants are indeed $F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$ and $F_{\mu\nu} (^\star F^{\mu\nu})$.
